# How can I choose a time once and give that time to all the days in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Currently I am using the following code

```
 <form method="POST" id="form3" onSubmit="return false;" data-parsley-validate="true" v-on:submit="invSubmit($event);">                                
                                        <h4 class="info-text">Give your Inventory and Work Hours ? </h4>
                                        <div class="row">  
                                            <div class="col-sm-6"> 
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Working Hours :</label>
                                                     <div v-for="value in day" class="checkboxFour">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id="need" value="value.val" v-model="value.selected" style="width: 10%!important;">
                                                      <label for="need" style=" width: 30%!important;">{{value.name}}</label>
  <select v-model="value.from" class="select-style" v-bind:class="{required: isRequired}" required="">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="09:00">09.00</option>
      <option value="10:00">10.00</option>
      <option value="11:00">11.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="13:00">13.00</option>
      <option value="14:00">14.00</option>
      <option value="15:00">15.00</option>
      <option value="16:00">16.00</option>
      <option value="17:00">17.00</option>
      <option value="18:00">18.00</option>
      <option value="19:00">19.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="21:00">21.00</option>
      <option value="22:00">22.00</option>
      <option value="23:00">23.00</option>
      <option value="00:00">00.00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01.00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02.00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03.00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04.00</option>
      <option value="05:00">05.00</option>
      <option value="06:00">06.00</option>
      <option value="07:00">07.00</option>
    </select>
    <select v-model="value.to" class="select-style" required="">To
      <option value="17:00">17.00</option>
      <option value="18:00">18.00</option>
      <option value="19:00">19.00</option>
      <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
      <option value="21:00">21.00</option>
      <option value="22:00">22.00</option>
      <option value="23:00">23.00</option>
      <option value="00:00">00.00</option>
      <option value="01:00">01.00</option>
      <option value="02:00">02.00</option>
      <option value="03:00">03.00</option>
      <option value="04:00">04.00</option>
      <option value="05:00">05.00</option>
      <option value="06:00">06.00</option>
      <option value="07:00">07.00</option>
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
      <option value="09:00">09.00</option>
      <option value="10:00">10.00</option>
      <option value="11:00">11.00</option>
      <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
      <option value="13:00">13.00</option>
      <option value="14:00">14.00</option>
      <option value="15:00">15.00</option>
      <option value="16:00">16.00</option>
    </select>
    <br>

  </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
              <div class="wizard-footer">
                       <div class="pull-right">
                               <button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next'>Next</button>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
         </div></form>
```

When I do this way I need to select working hours for each checkbox I am using. This is time consuming. I need to firstly choose a working hour and automatically choose that working hour for the checkboxes I am choosing. If I need to change a particular time for a checkbox, I need to do that too. How Can I able to achieve the same.

My vue js code is

```
submitBox = new Vue({
el: "#submitBox",
  data: {
   data: [],
    day:[
    {name:"Sunday",val:1},
    {name:"Monday",val:2},
    {name:"Tuesday",val:3},
    {name:"Wednesday",val:4},
    {name:"Thursday",val:5},
    {name:"Friday",val:6},
    {name:"Saturday",val:7}
    ],
    string:'',
  },



methods: {
     invSubmit: function(e) {
    var arr = [];
    this.day.map(function(v,i) {
     console.log(v.selected == true,);
     if(v.selected == true) 
      {
      arr.push(v.val+'&'+v.from+'&'+v.to);
      }
    });
    this.string = arr.join(',');
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['inv'] = this.inv.join(',');
           data['wrk_list'] = this.string;
           data['pid'] = this.pid;
             data['auth-token'] = this.authType;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/alpha/add/post/inv_whr/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
              if (e.status)
              {

                $("#alertModal").modal('show');
              $(".alert").removeClass("hidden").html("Your data has been successfully recorded");

            }
              else {
                vm.response = e;

               alert("Registration Failed") 
              }
          }
            });
            return false;
},
   }
```

I need to pass the data in the following format v.val+'&'+v.from+'&'+v.to. I t is been done as the above code.

How can I able to select a working hour first and then choose the days. If I need to change a workhour for a particular day, I need to do that too.

Please help me to have a solution. I am weak in js. This is the first time I am doing a project. Please help me to obtain a solution.

Comment: do you want to add selected hours to selected days? Also have you considered using a time picker instead of the times in dropdown.

Comment: yes sir i need a time picker,, how to do that